# Where can I find the GNU ar file format specification?

Tags: linux, gnu, unix-ar

I need to access an ar created file, but I cannot find a specification document defining the format.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Is the `ar` a static library? You might perhaps use `libbfd` ....

Comment: I'm using ar to package arbitrary files.  I'm not trying to access something output by a linker.  ar gives me a simple way to bundle files together.

Comment: I then would use some more usual format, like `tar` .... See `tar(5)` man page or `<tar.h>` header for its description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_%28Unix%29#File_format_details):

> The ar format has never been standardized; modern archives are based on a common format with two known variants, BSD and GNU.

More information is there, too.

Comment: Thanks!  My google-skills failed me on this one.  Glad yours had better success.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP is asking for the GNU ar format.

Answer (score 2):

### Where to find information

It seems that GNU binutils does not have documentation for the file format.

I believe the best reference out there is in the [ar(5) manual page from FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ar&sektion=5&manpath=FreeBSD+4.11-RELEASE). The `ar` utility was removed in version 5.0 but the manpage for 4.11 is still available.

As usual, the header details can be found in the header files:

- [GNU Binutils - ar.h](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=include/aout/ar.h;h=471a859fc57c7d8207193718610980f6bf2f83b3;hb=2cb5c79dad39dd438fb0f7372ac04cf5aa2a7db7)
- [FreeBSD - src/usrbin/ar.h](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/release/4.11.0/include/ar.h?revision=140576&view=markup) (it was removed some time ago, but it is still in the version control).

Also, the [Wikipedia page for the AR file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_%28Unix%29#File_format_details) has a nice diagram that describes the file format (it is from a .deb package which is also an `ar` file).

### File format

This file has a very simple structure:

- File signature (the one that identifies this as an `ar` file).
- For every file in the archive we have:

  - A header that contains file name, owner, group, size, and permissions (see header file).
  - The file contents
  - And optionally padding (\n).

Comment: "It seems that GNU binutils does not have documentation for the file format."  -- that's my concern here; how can someone maintain code to work properly if there is no spec?

Comment: To be honest, 'ar' is a dying format. Debian (.deb) packages are `.ar`files and they implemented their own ar encoder/decoder instead of using the `ar` utility see [DPKG ar.c](https://git.dpkg.org/cgit/dpkg/dpkg.git/tree/lib/dpkg/ar.c)

Comment: "To be honest, 'ar' is a dying format." So if I'm programming in C for embedded systems, what format would you expect me to use in the future for statically-linked libraries? I would have to disagree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Some information on IBM website:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.files%2Fdoc%2Faixfiles%2Far_big.htm

Comment: This is valid for AIX Big Format, which has a different magic marker and probably a different structure. AIX global header is much more complicated than GNU/BSD format documented on Wikipedia.